# function() is not a function in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am getting this error when calling a function in dojo:

> TypeError: this.loadNameAndDescpFromLookup is not a function

But I dont know why ?:
here is my code

```js
readBarcodeFromMobile: function(){
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', function(event) {
            registry.byId('PId').set("value", event.body);
            this.loadNameAndDescpFromLookup(event.body); // the error is here
        });
    });
}            

loadNameAndDescpFromLookup: function(barcode){ }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `function()` *is* still a function. The problem is `this` is pointing at the wrong context.

Comment: "this" is pointing to the window

Comment: The context (`this`) has changed in the callback. To maintain the outer context you could use arrow functions: `stompClient.connect({}, (frame) => {` etc.

Comment: @Andy but it doesnt work with arrows

Comment: What doesn't work with arrows?

Comment: that line this.sockets.push(this.socket);

Comment: @firstNamelastName check out my answer below. Basically - capture `this` in a variable so it's accessible in your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the others pointed out, the problem is that `this` doesn't refer to the object you want to use inside of the function.

The solution would be to store the `this` context in the variable and refer to it later.

For example

```
readBarcodeFromMobile: function(){
const self = this; // save the `this` context in a variable
this.socket = SockJS('/controller/Barcode');
this.sockets.push(this.socket);
stompClient = Stomp.over(this.socket);
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', function(event) {
      if(registry.byId('productBarcodeId') != undefined){
        registry.byId('productBarcodeId').set("value", event.body);
        self.loadNameAndDescpFromLookup(event.body); // use the stored context
      }
    });
 });
} 
loadNameAndDescpFromLookup: function(barcode){ }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the `this`.

Part of your code:

```
function(event) {
  if(registry.byId('productBarcodeId') != undefined){
    registry.byId('productBarcodeId').set("value", event.body);
    this.loadNameAndDescpFromLookup(event.body); // the error is here
  }
}
```

Here the `this`is refering to the `function` and not  Object you wrote the whole Code in.
But obviousley the function does not have the specified dunction and therefore the Error occurs.

I´m not really sure how to do this properly, but you could use a variable to store the needed context and use the variable instead of the `this`.

Example:

```html
<head>
<style>
#btn1, #btn2 {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<Body>
<Button id="btn1">Working</Button>
<Button id="btn2">Error</Button>
<script>
init();
function init() {
 var currentThis = this; //Here the right this-context is stored in a variable
 document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function() {
                  currentThis.test(); //here the var currentThis will be used to find the right scope
 }
        document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function() {
                  this.test(); //Here an Error will occur
 }
}

function test() {
 alert("working");
}
</script>
</Body>
```

Comment: so any solution ?

Comment: `Here the this is refering to the function` no, it would refer to the *execution context*. That's not necessarily (and not often) going to be the function itself for a callback.

Comment: `here the var currentThis will be used to find the right scope` also, that happens to work by somewhat of an accident in the example. The value of `this` will be `window`. As it happens `function test()` is an implied global, so it gets attached to `window` object, hence why `this.test()` works. That is **not** going to work if the code is wrapped in an IIFE (which is what would normally be the case). Even without and IIFE the same code won't work when using strict mode.

Comment: @vlaz thats why I noted, that i don´t how how to do it properly, since you seem to have some knowledge regading this topic, please feel free to provide a correct solution. I don´t mind learning this myself :)